# PHP imagecreate insert user avatar

Tags: php, php-gd

I have some problem i try to add user avatar on userbanner, but i have some problems because i cant show resized avatar just a part of photo..

I creating image with:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng('bannerbg.png');
```

Avatar for user is url to user photo...

Showing avatar with this code:

```
imagecopy($image, $avatar, 15, 19, 40, 20, 79, 79);
```

Any help how to show resized full image of user avatar just like

`<img src="avatarurl" style="width:50px;height:50px;">`

Regards

Comment: How do you define the size of `$image`?

Comment: Its not defined the code get the photo width and height its like width and height auto in css :)

Comment: I don't understand your question, what is *like `<img ...`*?

Comment: I just give an example for HTML what i need , i dont use that on banner script , i have problem with avatar its crop my avatar and show only part dont want to resize avatar just like html example i give <img ...

Answer (score 0):

Basically this:

```
<img src="yourscript.php">
```

and then script would be

```
<?php
... do image manipulation
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($gd);
```

But note that this would put a massive load on your system as it builds a new jpeg for EVERY request. Better option is to cache the image, and serve up the cached version instead of constant re-generation:

```
<img src="yourscript.php?id=someuser">

<?php

if (!cached_version_exists($_GET['someuser']);
   ... build image
   imagejpeg($gd, $path_to_file);
}
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile($path_to_file);
```

Comment: sure i use with $_GEt['username'] and thats all working i just need to show resized useravatar not just a part of useravatar